# how to get rating value dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, rating

I've using a rating system on my webpage. I've used [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/sabberworm/jStarbox) for it. This is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/565LK/5/). I want, rating number(for example, 2 out of 5 or 2/5 which is located right side of my jiddle) will also be changed at the time of changing star rating just like imdb.com. How can I make this?

jQuery:

```
$('.starbox').starbox({
    average: 0.42,
    autoUpdateAverage: true,
    ghosting: true
});
```

Comment: I've invented a rating system which is CSS only btw, so you don't need javascript.. 
http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/qvhtf

Comment: This is good. But, I've to make it compatible with IE8 too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check this one?
Here the right line is updated on hover, and when you leave the star, it put back the initial value corresponding to the highlighted stars

```
$('.starbox').starbox({
    average: 0.4,
    autoUpdateAverage: true,
    ghosting: true
});

$('.star').hover(function() {
    var currentHoveredNote = parseInt($(this).attr('class').replace("star star-", "")) + 1;
    $(this).closest(".block").find(".rating-value p").text(currentHoveredNote + '/5');
}, function() {
    $(this).closest(".block").find(".rating-value p").text(parseFloat($(this).closest(".starbox").starbox("getOption", "average")) * 5 + '/5');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/565LK/12/

Comment: the plugin you used can be perfected with this kind of things ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the range to be from 1 to 5, you should have average set to either of {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0} since the control takes values in range 0.0 to 1.0.
Next you need to bind to an event `starbox-value-moved` and to show the selected value when the cursor is hovered like:

```
.bind('starbox-value-moved', function(event, value) {
    $('.rating-value p').text(value * 5 + '/5');
});
```

And for click you need to bind it to `starbox-value-changed`.

Comment: Not sure it's what the OP asked for: he wants updated value when hovering a star (see imdb website)

Comment: @NicolasR thanks for the feedback. Updated the answer for hovering over the starts. Not sure how imdb website rating control looks like though. I don't have access to it at work.

Comment: yes, I need it both for click and hover action on star just like imdb website

Comment: @user1896653: do you need to display the current rate selected by the user, or the average (calculated with other rates)?

Comment: it's okay now @rageit. but, when number is changed, it's move to the top! I don't know why, the style is changing at the time of value changing. http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/565LK/7/

Comment: @NicolasR for now, I need to display the current rate selected by the user

Comment: the number moved to top because you are missing the `p` previously used. See http://jsfiddle.net/565LK/8/
But that's still not perfect I think: when you leave the stars, the previous modified value is still there..;

Comment: @NicolasR yep, answer updated. p needs to be added after rating-value.

Comment: yes, it's okay now. Just noticed that one rating value changing change the other rating's value too. It shouldn't do this. http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/565LK/10/

Comment: value still wrong when leaving the hover! See my answer to handle this problem

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
        $('.starbox').each(function() {
            var starbox = $(this);
            starbox.starbox({
                average: 0.4,
                changeable: true,
                ghosting: true,
                autoUpdateAverage: true,
            }).bind('starbox-value-changed', function(event, value) {                   
                    starbox.next().text(value*5+"/5");
            }).bind('starbox-value-moved', function(event, value) {
                starbox.next().text(value*5+"/5");
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: it's good. Because, one rating value change don't make effect on other rating. But, the number go to the top at the time of value changing. I tried to fix this like this way: starbox.next('.rating-value p').text(value*5+"/5"); But, this is not the right things. I am not good at jquery. That's why, I can't write the correct code for it. http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/565LK/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this portion of code:

```
$(".block").each(function (ix, item) {
    var average = $(".starbox", item).starbox("getOption", "average");

    $(".rating-value p", item).text((5 * average).toFixed(0) + "/5");
});
```

See [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/565LK/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Add the binding for starbox-value-moved after your current function:

```
$('.starbox').starbox({
    average: 0.62,
    autoUpdateAverage: true,
    ghosting: true
}).bind('starbox-value-moved', function(event, value) {
    $('.rating-value p').text((value * 5) + "/5");
});
```

The value is 0 - 1, so you'll need to multiply it up to get it to go from 0 - 5.